# R session Aborted in using RODBC

Tags: r, rodbc, qsqlquery

I just want to write some data into oracle, I have already set up the table in oracle, the structure of table is

```
Name:       ID   TAGCODE  FAULTID  MATRIX  CREATETIME  VALID     TYPE
Data Type:Number varchar2 number   BLOB     date      varchar2  Number
```

I wrote this code to realize my goal:

```
library(RODBC)
channel<-odbcConnect(dsn="bigdata",uid="swapdata",pwd="swap123",believeNRows=FALSE)
ID<-2
TAGCODE<-c("test1")
FAULTID<-1
CREATETIME<-as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
VALID<-c("t")
TYPE<-1
MATRIX<-paste(readBin("test.csv",what="raw",n=1e6),collapse="")
sql<-paste("insert into T_FORECAST_AI_LIBRARY values(",ID,",'",TAGCODE,"',",FAULTID,",'",MATRIX,"','",CREATETIME,"','",VALID,"',",TYPE,"",sep="")
sqlQuery(channel,sql)
```

MATRIX is just a file in `csv` format, the size of Matrix is about 28`kb`
when I run the code, R session go to be aborted,

Answer (score 0):

Install an ODBC driver connector on your machine. Download it from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-096177.html and configure it with your oracle credential and try again.